# JQuery setting z-index not working

Tags: jquery, css

I've got a problem with JQuery refusing to set the z-index of an element. Not just to a certain amount, but to any amount at all! I set it when building the elements through JQuery (but that's just in the append code), and then try to set it again in the function that swaps the images around. But when it gets the 9th iteration, it should set the z-index to 0, and instead doesn't, and juts ignores it. I've sat down and tried various different things to no avail, if anyone can help thta would be great.

The code for all of this is on this page: http://www.prideoftameside.co.uk/default-redesign.htm.

The specific part you'll need to be looking at is:

```
function loadImage(number) {
 if (number) {
    imagecount = number;
}

if (imagecount == 1) {
    $('#introimages > img:nth-child(1)').css({'z-index' : 9 });
}

$('#introimages > img:nth-child(' + imagecount + ')').animate({'opacity' : 0 }, 2000)

$('#introimages > img:nth-child(' + (imagecount + 1) + ')').css({'opacity' : 1 });

if (imagecount == 9) {
    $('#introimages > img:nth-child(1)').css({'opacity' : 1, 'z-index' : 0 });
    imagecount = 0;
}

imagecount += 1;
}
```

Which is called via the SetInterval on line 246.

Thanks in advance.

James

Answer (score 0):

Took a glance at your script file...

Your z-index setting logic works correctly (tested in separately in Chrome Dev), looks more like the function the logic resides in never gets called (surrounding break points were never triggered.)

I recommend taking a closer look at your script using Chrome's built-in debugging tools.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html#debug

[If helpful please mark so. :) ]

Comment: Hi,

I've had a look at it in the Chrome debugger, and it was definitely calling that function, as well as going through that if statement, and executing the JQuery selector as expected. I've now tweaked the code and instead used :eq as the selector, which worked as expected. Not sure why nth-child was having issues when setting the z-index, but it was definitely the selector that was the problem.